# Python: Merging two PDF/A or converting regular PDF into PDF/A

Tags: python, pdf

I wish to merge two PDF 1/A documents resulting in one single PDF 1/A, is this possible using Python? I have been unable to find a library that supports this functionality. PikePDF can merge them so that the result conforms to PDF 1/A but it isn't a valid PDF 1/A document (it ends up as 1.3).

Another option would be to convert the PikePDF merge result into PDF 1/A but I am unable to find a Python library able to perform the conversion.

Any ideas?

Comment: @KJ Pikepdf does state it is able to preserve conformity with PDF/A but surely there has to be other differences. Or is it possible to simply change the tag and it becomes a valid PDF/A ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use pypdf2 and do something like this to merge pdf

```
import os, logging
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

def merge_pdf(self):
    try:
        merger = PdfFileMerger()
        for files in PDF_FILES:
            merger.append(os.path.join(PDF_BASE_PATH,files))
        merger.write(os.path.join(PDF_BASE_PATH,'merged.pdf'))
        merger.close()
    except Exception as e:
        response = str(e)
        logging.info(f'Merge Files : {response}')
        raise e
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use `PyPdf2` module ?

Try following code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

pdfs = ['file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf', 'file3.pdf']

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdfs:
    merger.append(pdf)

merger.write("result.pdf")
merger.close()
```

Comment: Pikepdf is said to be a more updated version of PyPDF2 but I just tried it and it has the same result as Pikepdf. The result is 1.3 and not a valid PDF/A, according to online PDF/A validation tools.

Comment: Maybe try to convert 1.3 to PDF/A after merge is done. I found some code it might help you. [link to code](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/py/PDFATest). Following link will lead you to the code that is using PDFTron SDK to programmatically convert generic PDF documents into ISO-compliant, VeraPDF-valid PDF/A files, or to validate PDF/A compliance.

Comment: Yes, PDFTron is the first result that pops up when googling. Although it seems to be the only relevant result it is unfortunately a commercial library; surely there has to be an open source alternative? I'm assuming this conversion is a relatively common use-case and I'm surprised there aren't other ways of accomplishing the task.